# DataGridView - ReadOnly Cell KeyDown Event

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, readonly

i have a datagridview with a readonly cell, i would like to show a formdialog window when the user press the space key. but is not possible since the cell is readonly=true.

i'v been using the following code with the EditingControlShowing event. and when the cell is readonly=false it works sometimes.

```
 Private Sub sub_fecha_keydown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs)
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Space Then
        Dim frm As New frmFecha
        frm.fecha_inicial = Me.m_dtp_id_fecha.Fecha
        Dim res As DialogResult = frm.ShowDialog()
        If res = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            Me.m_dgv_detalle.Rows(Me.m_dgv_detalle.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("m_dgv_dtm_documento").Value = frm.fecha_format
        Else
            Me.m_dgv_detalle.Rows(Me.m_dgv_detalle.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("m_dgv_dtm_documento").Value = ""
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

i would like to keep the cell readonly=true.

is there any other way to do it?

thanks very much for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to intercept a keystroke for a readonly cell, which may not be possible, why not add a button column next to the field and when it is pressed, perform your actions.

This way you don't have to worry about whether the cell is readonly or not and it will be easier for your users to understand how the form is to be accessed.

Here is a link to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncolumn.aspx) on the DataGridViewButtonColumn.

Comment: thansk you for your answer, i thought about that earlier. but i would like the user to use only the keyboard. does the cellclick event works also when the user press enter in a button cell?